# How can I find the custom app in App Manager after deploying the package?

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, deployment, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps

I've deployed the package using the following commands.

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config\project-scratch-def.json -a TestDebHub --setdefaultusername -v <developer_email>
sfdx force:source:push
sfdx force:org:open
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app -u <developer_email>
```

Could you let me know how I can find the custom app in App Manager after deploying the package?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have permission assigned for you current user to access the newly created app?

Comment: Yes, I have the permission